# Contribute Federal and State withholdings to company 401k instead?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 401k, retirement, state-income-tax

So I am attempting to devise a way to max my company retirement account. They offer 3% of my annual pay if I put in at least 6% of my annual pay.

The problem is that I don't want to take a giant chuck out of my paycheck every two weeks. I would much prefer contribute in one lump sum. That being said, the company will only match it if it 1. comes out of my paycheck and 2. is spread over the year.

The solution I devised is this. If I stop my federal and state tax contributions it is roughly the equivalent to what I need. My paycheck wouldn't change in amount, I would get the complete matching from the company and I wouldn't have to rethink my budget for the year.

I know this sounds like a horrible idea at first but most of my annual income is untaxed because it's rental income. So I end up having to pay every year anyhow. I could just take what I was planning on contributing to my retirement fund and use it for taxes instead.

**My question is,** Is this feasible/legal? How do I request that the company doesn't withold anything? Is there a legitimate way to do this?

What they withhold is jacked up anyway. They only withhold 25% and I am in the 28% tax bracket usually so I have to pay on it twice.

Comment: Please remember the "united-states" tag when you're asking about taxes.

Comment: "and 2. is spread over the year." Are you sure? How would they define "spread over the year"? I think how matching usually works is, they match a certain percent of your contributions, up to a certain percentage of your the paycheck *for each paycheck*. Not for the year. So each paycheck you are limited in how much match you can get, and you must spread it out over the year to get the maximal match. I think it is likely this is what's happening and you're confused about the terms.

Comment: "They only withhold 25% and I am in the 28% tax bracket" Tax bracket just means what your last dollar of income is taxed at. Some of your income will be taxed at 25%, some at 15%, some at 10%, and some will be exempt. Your effective federal income tax rate from work will be much lower than 25%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask your employer to add more exemptions so that they withhold less taxes from your paycheck.

However, this is a really bad idea; you're not supposed to knowingly claim an inaccurate number of exemptions. If at the end of the year, you owe the IRS too much when you file your taxes, they will hit you with a penalty. Find out more about the penalty [here](http://www.forbes.com/sites/advisor/2012/06/25/understanding-the-underpayment-penalty-and-how-to-avoid-it/).

Comment: So what if I am totally self employed? Currently 2/3rds of my income comes from rental properties I own and that's untaxed until the end of the year. Why should I be penalized for that? I don't see any reason I should be punished for wanting to pay all my taxes during tax season.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Because the U.S tax system is a "pay as you earn" system; so you're supposed to pay taxes on the money you earn as you earn it, not in a lump sum at the end of the year.

Comment: Well I don't like that system. I'm going to read more about this penalty. The government doesn't control me. I do what I want.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell you sound like you're a 3-year old. There are rules, and everyone play by the rules.

Comment: If no one ever challenged the rules humanity wouldn't progress.